# Proof about cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let $f:G \rightarrow H$ be an isomorphism between groups $G$ and $H$. Show that G is cyclic if and only if H is cyclic.

Approach: we have to show both directions

1) if G is cyclic then H is cyclic
2) if H is cyclic then G is cyclic.

Proof 1)

If $G$ is cyclic then $G=<a>$ where $a\in G$, so every $b\in G$ can be represented as $b=a^t$ where $t\in Z$. Since $f$ is surjective and injective for every $v\in H$, there exists a unique $p \in G$ such that $f(p)=v$ and $p=a^t$, so we can say 
$$v=f(p)=f(a^t)=f(a*a^{t-1})=f(a)*f(a^{t-1})=f(a)*f(a*a^{t-2})=f(a)*(f(a)*f(a^{t-2}))=....=f(a)^t$$

We can get rid of the parentheses at the end hence H is associative. The latter shows that every element in H can be represented in the form $f(a)^t$ where $t \in Z$, so H is cyclic. How does that look?

we know that $f^{-1}$ is bijective , but how do we know it is homomorphic?. I think that for part b we have to use the same trick but now with $f^{-1}$

Comment: You are right. Part b is just part a with $f^{-1}$.

Comment: how do we show $f^{-1}$ is homomorphic?

Comment: Let $x,y$ be two elements of $H$. Let $f^{-1}(x) = a$ and $f^{-1}(y) = b$. Then applying $f$ on both sides, $x = f(a)$ and $y=f(b)$, hence $x+y=f(a)+f(b) = f(a+b)$, and by applying $f^{-1}$, we get $f^{-1}(x+y) = a+b = f^{-1}(x) + f^{-1}(y)$. Hence $f^{-1}$ is homomorphic. Similarly it will be isomorphic too.

Comment: Looks like to me that you can just relabel and call $f^{-1} = g: H \to G$

Comment: I'd say there is nothing to prove here, even if you don't know what "cyclic" means.

Answer (score 1):

The "main part" of your proof of 1) can be improved by proving this first:

If $f:G \to H$ is a homomorphism, and $g \in G, k \in \Bbb Z$, then $f(g^k) = [f(g)]^k$.

Maybe you have already proven this; if not, prove it for $k > 0$ by induction, the special case $k = 0$, and using, for $k > 0$, the rule $g^{-k} = (g^{-1})^k$.

You seem to have some concerns that $f^{-1}$ may not be a homomorphism. Since $f$ is bijective, it is surjective. Let $h_1,h_2 \in H$ be arbitrary. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $g_1,g_2 \in G$, with $f(g_1) = h_1$ and $f(g_2) = h_2$. Since $f$ is injective, these are unique, and are the images:

$f^{-1}(h_1),f^{-1}(h_2)$ of the $h_i$ under the function $f^{-1}$. We want to show:

$f^{-1}(h_1\ast h_2) = f^{-1}(h_1)\ast f^{-1}(h_2) = g_1 \ast g_2$.

Now $f(f^{-1}(h_1\ast h_2)) = h_1\ast h_2 = f(g_1) \ast f(g_2) = f(g_1 \ast g_2)$, since $f$ is a homomorphism.

Since $f$ is injective, we have $f^{-1}(h_1\ast h_2) = g_1 \ast g_2$, QED.